# conditional formatting for custom format

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

I am using excel 2013.
I want to create a rule for conditional formatting like as below:
The format is "hh:mm tt- hh:mm tt".

I values for this format is like as below-
1. 10:00 AM-11:13 AM
2. 11:49 AM-01:00 PM
3. 05:50 PM-08:44 PM etc.

I have tried like this
=AND(LEFT(A1, 2) > 0, LEFT(A1, 2) < 12, RIGHT(A1, 2) = "AM")
=AND(LEFT(A1, 2) > 0, LEFT(A1, 2) < 12, RIGHT(A1, 2) = "PM")
but did not get succeed.

Please provide a solution.

Comment: What is it stuck on? How are your values being entered? Are they being pulled from elsewhere or manually entered? The "AND" command is only going to get you a T/F statement, not really anything to work towards.

Comment: @JoeLaviano: The excel sheet is preparing by coding in c#, not entered manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MID (cellno., startindex, length) can be used and matched for the followiling patterrn

> 10:00 AM-11:13 AM

You could try this

```
=AND(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))>0,VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))<=12, MID(A1, 3, 1)=":", VALUE(MID(A1,4,2)) >= 0, VALUE(MID(A1,4,2)) < 60,OR(MID(A1,6,3)=" AM",MID(A1,6,3)=" PM"), MID(A1,9,1)="-", VALUE(MID(A1,10,2))>0,VALUE(MID(A1,10,2))<=12, MID(A1, 12, 1)=":", VALUE(MID(A1,13,2)) >= 0, VALUE(MID(A1,13,2)) < 60, OR(MID(A1,15,3)=" AM",MID(A1,15,3)=" PM"))
```